# Streamlining looping through lists and dictionaries in Python based on certain true expressions

Tags: python

I am trying to right an elegant, shorter way than a bunch of loop statements (like LINQ in .Net or lambda expressions in TypeScript: map => {} ), but not quite sure how or if it is possible.

I have two objects like so:

```
# Input objects
input_object.id = "Hello"
# A list of integers
input_object.values = [2,3,4,5,6]

# Basic object my_object that has two properties
my_object.name = "Hello"
# The key in this dictionary are strings but are always valid numbers
my_object.codes = {"1": "Howdy_There", "2": "Thank_You", "3": "Thank_you" }
```

I can do something like this:

```
saved_names = []

if input.id ==  my_object.name

    #This will match for the above case
    # Now I want to go through all the my_object.codes and see if that key is in input_object.values
    # and if it is append the value to the save_names list
    
    # Something like below
    # This is my psuedo code attempt
    for c in my_object.codes
        if c (as an int) is in list input_object.values
            saved_names.append(add c's value)

# Now make the saved_names list unique values only
saved_names = (make saved names unique somehow)
```

Is there a way to streamline this without all the loops like some built in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want a set comprehension

```
saved_names = set(v for k, v in codes.items() if int(k) in values)
```

Which translates to

> Get a unique set of values from the key-value pairs of the `code` dictionary, but only the values where the key (as an int) is in the `values` list

Note: dictionary keys do not need to be strings

Comment: Exactly. I knew there was a way in python as I can do it in .Net and TypeScript but new to python - thanks

Comment: Yes the dictionary keys are part of a bigger picture that was already written as strings but yes they could be ints